# Root of equation, solvability

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

I was trying to solve the following equation for t

$$(P\cdot l \cdot \exp(-l\cdot t) + R \cdot l \cdot \exp(-l \cdot t))/t + (P \cdot \exp(-l \cdot t) + R \cdot (\exp(-l \cdot t) - 1))/t^2 = 0 $$

Being a little bit nasty, I tried to put this equation on MATLAB, but it says "Explicit solution could not be found".

Is it easy to see numerically that the solution actually exists.

So my question is:
1) why the solution cannot be found?
2) is there any criteria to check solvability of algebric equations? (any external source link is welcomed)
3) can I find any approximation of the solution?

Thank you very much.

EDIT: P, R and l are strictly positive.

Comment: This equation is only "algebraic" if you are in the context of DAE. If not, this is, after multiplication with $t^2$, an analytical equation, i.e., concerning the roots of power series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to solve the equation in terms of a finite number of elementary functions. But it is possible thanks to a special function: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html

[image]

Comment: Sorry JJacquelin, but I have to take out the correct answer flag, because I cannot get the right result with your formula. 
Example: R=1; P=1; l=0.5; Numerically I can see that this function is equal to zero at 3.4. 
Your equation gives me -1.53. 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: In fact, the formula is exact, but the LambertW function is a multi valuated function in the range $-1/e<X<0$. In this range, there are two real roots. One have to test which one is convenient for solving the initial equation. $W(X)$ is an old symbol. It should be less confusing to use the "Product Log" function symbol $W_k(X)$ so that the two possible values are $W_0(X)$ and $W_{-1}(X)$ in the range $-1/e<X<0$. In the case $l=0.5 ; R=P=1$ we observe that the convenient value is $W_{-1}(1/(2e))=-2.768347$ leading to $t=3.356694$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LambertW%28-1%2C-1%2F%282e%29%29

Comment: Correction of a typo in my comment : $W_{-1}(-1/2e)=-2.768347$

Comment: This is clear, thank you.

Comment: After more thinking, the root corresponding to $W_0(-1/(2e))=-0.231961$ is also convenient. It leads to $t=-1.536078$. Your equation has two real roots. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=LambertW%280%2C-1%2F%282e%29%29

Comment: Moreover, I would mention that the formula allows to compute the complex roots of the equation. You can try with $W_2$ or $W_{-2}$ or other integer $k$ in $W_k$. The complex values obtained  leads to complex values of $t$ which are other roots of the equation.